# Video Stats - youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

I'm getting video stats via api call. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djSHYd-BhMQ in this video has only one comment but API returns 0 as you can see from here [ATTACHMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mAYY.png). This is also happening if you try to call this via Youtube API Explorer. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true#try-it_1

Best Regards,

Comment: "This video has been removed for violating YouTube's Terms of Service."

Comment: this is happening in every video. do not take this video serious. its not related with the video. if you do only one comment any video and if that video has only one comment, youtube api returns comment=0. if you do your 2nd comment then youtube api returns comment=2. if you remove all of your two comments, youtube api still returns comment=1.